# Deep LSTM accuracy not crossing 50%

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, nlp, lstm

I am working on a classification problem of the semeval 2017 task 4A [dataset can be found here](http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2017/task4/index.php?id=data-and-tools)
and I am using deep LSTM network for it. In pre-processing, I have done lower casing->tokenization->lemmatization->removing stop words->removing punctuations. For word embeddings, I have used WORD2VEC model. There are 18,000 samples in my training set and 2000 samples in testing.

The code for my model is

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 30, input_length=max_len))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, use_bias=True, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, use_bias=True, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(128, 1,64)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(SeqSelfAttention(attention_activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

The value of **max_words** is 2000 and **max_len** is 300

But even after this, my testing accuracy is not crossing 50%. I can't figure out the problem.
PS - I am using validation technique too. The loss function is '**Binary Crossentropy**' and optimizer is '**Adam**'.

Comment: What loss function are you using?

Comment: @alift Binary crossentropy and optimizer is Adam

Comment: How much is the accuracy for training examples? if it is near to 50% as well, you might suffer from underfitting

Comment: @alift the training accuracy gradually increases from 30-35% to 50%. So you might be correct that the model is underfitting. But, I have also tried inccreasing the LSTM layer from 32 to 64, yet it only increases computational time with no effect on accuracy.

Comment: How much data do you have? You might not have enough. If that is the case, making your model bigger will worsen the problem. Before enlargening the model, I would go by decreasing the dropout.

Comment: @alift My training data is 18,568 rows and testing is 2,064. I am also using validation set while training which is 20% of training set. Does this seem small as compared to the deep lstm I am using? Also, my dropout for input layer is 0.3, for 1st hidden layer is 0.5 and 2nd hidden layer is 0.5. How much do I decrease the dropout if it can resolve this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214797/discussion-between-alift-and-amber-bhanarkar).

Answer (score 0):

Training "LSTM" is very different with other common deep learning model. 
I recommend a higher dropout rate like 0.7,0.8. and Adam optimizer is particularly unstable in LSTM with real world data. So, i recommend SGD scheduled for a momentum of 0.9 and ReduceLROnPlateau. You have to do very long training, and if spark loss is observed, the training is going very well. (Spark Loss is a word used by NVIDIA researchers. It refers to a phenomenon in which the value of Loss that appears to converge increases significantly.)

Comment: Can you explain how increasing dropout can help here? dropout is a mechanism which helps for a better generalization, against overfitting. Lower dropout, you risk more overfitting, higher dropout, you risk more underfitting. Here, the issue seems that the model is getting underfit. If that assumption is correct, then increasing the dropout will make it worse, right?